# Setting Archive Quotas by Mailbox database (Exchange 2010 SP1)

Tags: exchange-2010, archive, quota

We're working on setting up archiving and quotas on our Exchange 2010 server, we would like to create two databases for primary mailboxes, and two for archive mailboxes.

We can set quotas on the database for the primary mailboxes by setting the limits on the DB, then under the user's mailbox, it uses the default for the DB.

Can we set quotas for the archive mailbox the same way somehow? So that the DB has a default archive database Quota, and then putting people's archive mailbox into that DB automatically assigns the quota, or do we have to set the archive quota for each mailbox individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. The archive quota is set on a per user basis.